# TX1 OpenCV VideoCapture fails to open SDP configuration file

Tags: c++, opencv, gstreamer-1.0

I want to use GStreamer to capture the video content of the IP camera and compress it to the H.264 stream server, and then uses OpenCV+GStreamer to receive the H.264 video stream on nvidia TX1.Here is my gstreamer pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -ve rtspsrc location=rtsp://admin:12345@192.168.1.64/Streaming/Channels/1 ! nvvidconv flip-method=6 ! 'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=(int)960, height=(int)540, format=(string)I420, framerate=(fraction)30/1' ! omxh264enc control-rate=2 bitrate=4000000 ! 'video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream' ! h264parse ! queue ! omxh264dec ! nvvidconv ! 'video/x-raw, format=(string)UYVY' ! videoconvert ! jpegenc quality=30 ! rtpjpegpay ! udpsink host=$CLIENT_IP port=5000 sync=false async=false
```

The above code captures and compresses the content of the camera into the H.264 video stream of 30 frames of 960p, and sends it to the network port of the board through the UDP protocol [5000].It runs successfully and here is my
code of client:

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>  
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>  
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>  
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>  
#include <opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp>  

using namespace cv;  

int main(int, char**)  
{  
  VideoCapture input("./stream.sdp");  
  if(!input.isOpened()){  // check if we succeeded                                                                                                                                                                       
    std::cout<< "open failed" << std::endl;  
    return -1;  
  }  

  Mat img, img_gray;  
  OrbFeatureDetector detector(7000);  
  vector<KeyPoint> img_keypoints, car_keypoints;  
  Mat img_descriptors, car_descriptors;  

  input.read(img);  
  Mat car;  
  img(Rect(400, 320, 150, 100)).copyTo(car);  

  detector(car, Mat(), car_keypoints, car_descriptors);  
  drawKeypoints(car, car_keypoints, car);  
  for(;;)  
    {  
      if(!input.read(img))  
        break;  
      detector(img, Mat(), img_keypoints, img_descriptors);  
      drawKeypoints(img, img_keypoints, img);  


      BFMatcher matcher;  
      vector<DMatch> matches;  
      matcher.match(car_descriptors, img_descriptors, matches);  

      vector<Point2f> car_points, img_points;  
      for(int i=0; i < matches.size(); ++i){  
        car_points.push_back(car_keypoints[matches[i].queryIdx].pt);  
        img_points.push_back(img_keypoints[matches[i].queryIdx].pt);  
      }  
      std::cout<<"car points count = " << car_points.size() << std::endl;  

      if(car_points.size() >= 4){  
        Matx33f H = findHomography(car_points, img_points, CV_RANSAC);  

        vector<Point> car_border, img_border;  
        car_border.push_back(Point(0, 0));  
        car_border.push_back(Point(0, car.rows));  
        car_border.push_back(Point(car.cols, car.rows));  
        car_border.push_back(Point(car.cols, 0));  
        for (size_t i = 0; i < car_border.size(); ++i){  
          Vec3f p = H * Vec3f(car_border[i].x, car_border[i].y, 1);  
          img_border.push_back(Point(p[0]/p[2], p[1]/p[2]));  
        }  
        polylines(img, img_border, true, CV_RGB(255, 255, 0));  
        Mat img_matches;  
        drawMatches(car, car_keypoints, img, img_keypoints, matches, img_matches);  
        imshow("img_matches", img_matches);  
      }  
      // imshow("car", car);                                                                                                                                                                                             
      // imshow("img", img);                                                                                                                                                                                             
      if(waitKey(27) >= 0) break;  
    }  
  // the camera will be deinitialized automatically in VideoCapture destructor                                                                                                                                           
  return 0;  
}
```

The configuration file CMakeLists.txt is as follows:

```
project(hello)  
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)  
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})  
add_executable(cv_hello hello.cpp)  
target_link_libraries(cv_hello ${OpenCV_LIBS}
```

The client code can be compiled successfully but when it runs, `VideoCapture input("./stream.sdp")`will fail to open the sdp file and return "open failed".Here is my stream.sdp file:

```
c=IN IP4 127.0.0.1  
m=video 5000 RTP/AVP 96  
a=rtpmap:96 JPEG/4000000
```

I have tried to use absolute path and tried to set environment variables
`export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/ubuntu/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig : $PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to add ffmeg decorder but they all failed to solve the problem.
I use opencv 2.4.13 and gstreamer-1.0 on TX1.

Comment: Just noting that you should not have spaces around the colon in your `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`